# Парсинг подгружаемых страниц при помощи Grab

Tags: python, grab, синтаксический-анализ

После нажатия кнопки на странице подгружаются html-элементы. Как обработать нажатие кнопки при помощи grab и заново спарсить страницу?

Comment: grub или grab?

Comment: Не заметил ошибку. Grab, конечно же.

Comment: Фух, я так испугался, что даже зашёл почитать из почты..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab может работать только с формами через .set_input() и .submit(), для обработки javascript смотрите в сторону, например, PhantomJS.

Можно, конечно, получить элемент кнопки, найти ее обработчик нажатия, из функции вытащить ссылку или что там генерируется, но это очень муторно и результат будет всегда непредсказуем.